# Is there a way to run less without reverting the screen afterward?

Tags: less

I much prefer `less` over `more` for paging output since it has a much nicer command interface. However, it has the very annoying feature of clearing the screen back to its original state on exit. The *one* feature of `more` that I like is that it leaves the screen alone so you can see the state it was in when you decided to exit (usually at the end of the file).

Even running `less` in the `LESS_IS_MORE` emulation mode, the screen is cleared. Is there a way to prevent `less` from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`less -X file`

From the `less` man page:

> -X or --no-init
>
> Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
>   strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the
>   deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the
>   screen.